# VLC how to play all files that contain specific word

Tags: bash, vlc, grep, find

I would like to play all files in all subdirectories that contain specific term.
I tried it using:

```
find . -type f | grep Song | vlc
```

I think I might be misunderstanding how `|` works, because it doesn't pass `grep` output to vlc

Comment: Hello. It may be that VLC does not support that method of adding files. I do not think it does. See VLC support and ask them.

Comment: You should use http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/xargs.1.html

Answer (score 3):

A pipe `|` connects the standard output of one command to the standard input of another. However AFAIK `vlc` does not read a list of filenames from standard input - it expects "items" (the names of files, or streams) to be passed as command line *arguments*. So either:

```
find . -type f -name '*Song*' -exec vlc {} +
```

or

```
find . -type f -name '*Song*' -print0 | xargs -r0 vlc
```

Refer to the manual pages (`man find`, `man xargs`) for details. Note that you don't need `grep` - you can do a simple pattern match with `find` itself.